# How to find a function that triggers every second?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

http://nylbcsbc.org/t.html

Using dev tools, I was trying to modify a tag's property, as shown in the picture below:
[image]
I was trying to remove the whole `style` attribute of the `video` tag, but whenever I remove it, it will come back.
I guess this is due to some javascript function that is being executed repeatedly. My question is, how do I find this function and turn it off, so that I can modify the attributes as I do in other normal pages?

Comment: you can find the activity using the profiler or timeline devtools tabs

Comment: To add to @dandavis answer, you can use the timeline tab, making sure you have the JS Profiler options selected. Press the record button, then make your modification and wait for it to change back. Once it changes back, press the record button to stop the timeline. You should see some yellow lines or boxes on the screen which basically show a stack trace over time for the Javascript.

Comment: You would use the JW Player's onTime() function to do something when the video progresses, maybe that would work for you? http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Answer (score 3):

To find the function that changes element's attribute:

Assuming you are using google-chrome: right click on the node in Elements panel, in the opened context menu select **Break on...** -> **Attribute Modification**; When it breaks, use call stack window to find the cause.

UPDATE:
If you can't control the code, like in your case with jwplayer, instead of trying to remove *style* attribute, try to override each CSS rule defined there with his initial value:

```
<style type="text/css">
    video {
      -webkit-transform: initial!important;
      transform: initial!important;
      width: initial!important;
      height: initial!important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: NICE! I learn something every day, kudos. the menu options remind me that one can use a mutation observer...